# CSS page transitions and animations

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm working on a portfolio-site for a friend. The basics looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5h74qskg/2/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#menu"><div id="menu-show">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-item">
            <p>Front Page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="work">
        <div style="margin:120px;">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#menu"><div id="menu-show">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-item">
            <p>Work</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
        <div style="margin:120px;">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#menu"><div id="menu-show">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-item">
            <p>About</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div style="margin:120px;">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#home"><div id="menu-back">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-item">
            <p><a class="link" href="#work">work</a></p>
            <p><a class="link" href="#about">about</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #000;
}

#content {
    clear: both;
    margin: 120px;
}

#menu-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -102%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

#menu:target {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

#work, #about {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -102%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

#work:target, #about:target {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

#main-item, #menu-item {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;

}
```

**My questions are:**

- How can I make the transition between #menu and #work (or) #about
  without having the "Front Page" flashing by? Is there a way to hide the front page while transitioning to either work or about?
- Also; How do I make so that #about and #work swipes in from the
  right, instead of left(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a transition that is the same in as it is out. So when you select a new item your initial menu moves back in before the new one has come out. The result is that you see the page underneath momentarily.

You can add a [delay property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-delay-property) to CSS transitions, as well as the property, duration and easing. If you then have a delay on the transition of the menu going back it will wait for the one coming out to be in position before it animates out. In fact, once that nav menu is hidden behind the new one, you may not need to animate it at all, you can just shift it back instantly - depends what your transition is doing.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #000;
}
#content {
    clear: both;
    margin: 120px;
}
#menu-nav {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -102%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -moz-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -o-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -ms-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    background: red;
}
#menu:target {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    background: orange;
}
#work, #about {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -102%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -moz-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -o-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    -ms-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out .4s;
    background: green;
}
#work:target, #about:target {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: margin-left .4s ease-in-out;
    background: lightblue;
}
#main-item, #menu-item {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#menu"><div id="menu-show">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-item">
            <p>Front Page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="work">
        <div style="margin:120px;">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#menu"><div id="menu-show">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-item">
            <p>Work</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
        <div style="margin:120px;">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#menu"><div id="menu-show">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="main-item">
            <p>About</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div style="margin:120px;">
        <div id="menu-nav">
            <a href="#home"><div id="menu-back">MENU
            </div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-item">
            <p><a class="link" href="#work">work</a></p>
            <p><a class="link" href="#about">about</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is your code slightly modified. You have a duplicate transition on both the original and `:target` versions of the elements. When the element becomes the target the transition happens straightaway, but when it loses it's target status and goes back to being a regular element there is a delay on the transition - so it waits for the next target to be in place before disappearing.

I've also added in some `z-index` swapping, so that the target is always above the regular elements. If you just define the z-index on the main definition, it will cascade to the :target too.

Finally I added some bright background colours to the elements in their different states, just to enable you to see clearly what was going on.

One final note: If you've given `#menu` a width, I wouldn't expect you to then also have to define it on `#menu:target` - though I've left it in your code in case there is some other reason.

Comment: Thanks man! Trust me, the finished design is going to have a lot more colors. Any ideas on how I can make the about and work swipe in from the right, instead of from the left?

Comment: instead of `left: 0;` and `margin-left: -102%;` use the right equivalents? that should do it i think?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work... BUT I did clean up my code, and now everything works as it should. Thank you so much for your help!